# How to register a user's vote on a poll?

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, graph, vote

I'm developing a page (facebook.com/genericco) for testing reasons and to learn how to develop for facebook apps.

In this page I'm developing I made a custom layout for a question I created in facebook. I was able through the graph api to retrieve my own accounts questions and then the options, however I still don't know how would I register a vote when the user votes through my 'customized question'.

anyone can help me? pretty please? I'll show you a picture of me with my shirt off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API is designed only to allow you to create questions, not answer them programmatically.  You're just going to have to rely upon the user to answer them via the normal facebook UI.

Comment: aw I see...could I then use the facebook to create in my app some interaction like they do in the games so I could have this functionality or similar?

Comment: You can design your own questioning system (front end, middle tier and datastore) for registered users to partake in.

Comment: DMCS how could I do that? I mean, using facebook credentials but keeping all rest inside my website? What about facebook open graph? Creating actions I mean...

Comment: In your questioning system, utilize the facebook user id as the Primary Key of your user table in your system.  This followup question really deserves its own question on programmers.stackexchange.com as they tend to handle the "how can I program this" types of questions, while StackOverflow is more for the I've programmed this and it doesn't work type of questions.